# Redirecting to new page when user reaches page bottom: Alternate code for Safari?

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I have successfully used this code to get the page to redirect when the user scrolls to the bottom:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
window.location = "/portfolio";
}, 4000);});
```

It just doesn't seem to work on Mobile Safari unless you pull it down quite far and then it will trigger the wait time, then load the page. I think this would be bad for UX. Mobile Chrome seems to work okay, but there's many iPhones out there without Chrome. Any suggestions? I'm going nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a little leeway, so that it doesn't have to exactly match the document height.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 25) {
            window.location = "/portfolio";
        }
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly. Thank you very much!